# ggplot - change size of dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting points on a graph with ggplot and geom_point. The size of the dots corresponds to the magnitude of the data point. The magnitude goes from 2 to 10. I would like to draw the dots by applying a factor of 0.5 to their magnitude so that the sizes go from 1 to 5. In the legend, on the side of the graph, I would like to show the real magnitude from 2 to 10.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a condition to the geom\_point size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361557/how-to-add-a-condition-to-the-geom-point-size)

Comment: More of "I think you'll see the answer in there" vs a full dup.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1) Divide the magnitude by 2:

```
geom_point(aes(size = magnitude/2))
```

2) Use the `range = c(1,5)` parameter:

```
geom_point(aes(size = magnitude)) +
scale_size(range = c(1,5))
```