# Using ifelse to determine point size in r ggplot, works until legend is added

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2

I am trying to set up a graph where the size of the point is smaller if n == 0 than n > 0.  The code works until I add a legend.  Here is my code that works:

```
ggplot(len.oo, aes(x = TCL, y = n, colour = worm, shape = worm)) + ylim(0, 20) +
  geom_point(size = ifelse(len.oo$n == 0, 2, 4)) + 
  theme_bw() + xlab(expression(~italic("O. obscurus")~"TCL (mm)")) + ylab("Abundance") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="none")
```

that gives me:

[image: ggplot without legend]

as soon as i add a legend it gives me an error.  code with legend:

```
ggplot(len.oo, aes(x = TCL, y = n, colour = worm, shape = worm)) + ylim(0, 20) +
  geom_point(size = ifelse(len.oo$n == 0, 2, 4)) + 
  theme_bw() + xlab(expression(~italic("O. obscurus")~"TCL (mm)")) + ylab("Abundance") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position=c(0.2, 0.8)) + guides(size=FALSE)
```

gives me the error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3):
>   size

I've also tried `position = "top"` and the like to have the legend outside the plot and without the guides(`size=FALSE`)

I could easily make the graph without the legend and then make the legend without the size difference and use other software to copy and paste the legend on the image, but I would like to do all this in R.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361557/how-to-add-a-condition-to-the-geom-point-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a condition to the geom\_point size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361557/how-to-add-a-condition-to-the-geom-point-size)

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here: `geom_point(size = ifelse(len.oo$n == 0, 2, 4))`

I can't give you a direct solution because no data was provided, but I'd suggest adding a variable in your `len.oo` dataframe so that this variable (let's say you call it `size_n`) is either a 2 or a 4 if `n` is equal to 0 and then change the `ggplot` layer to `geom_point(aes(size = size_n))`.

You can create this new variable with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
len.oo <- mutate(len.oo, size_n = ifelse(n == 0, 2, 4))
```

Comment: thank you all, i was able to get it to work using the following code:

ggplot(len.oo, aes(x = TCL, y = n, colour = worm, shape = worm)) + ylim(0, 20) +
  geom_point(aes(size = n > 0)) + scale_size_manual(values = c(2, 4)) +
  theme_bw() + xlab(expression(~italic("O. obscurus")~"TCL (mm)")) + ylab("Abundance") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position=c(0.2, 0.8)) + guides(size=FALSE)