# conditional size and face in geom_text_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am working on a fairly large scatter plot, and I am using [ggrepel](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel) as a method to avoid overlapping labels. However, I need to distinguish between some data points, and the idea would be to also rely on `size` and `face` to do so.

I post the dataset:

```
structure(list(horizontal = c(-0.352696359157562, 0.780073940753937, 
0.0911642983555794, -0.153335213661194, -0.540096700191498, -0.615496337413788, 
0.310178399085999, 0.797275483608246, -0.157139003276825, -0.33426907658577, 
0.253628611564636, 0.474333256483078, 0.0280635561794043, -0.522810518741608, 
0.712112784385681, 0.156166926026344, 0.378900289535522, -0.10096962749958, 
-0.751460909843445, 0.000464908313006163, -0.368376433849335, 
-0.0745543912053108, -0.496564328670502, 0.703955709934235, -0.10785873234272, 
0.371504008769989, -0.586291670799255, 0.191669017076492, -0.154560878872871, 
0, 0.843597233295441, 0.449101448059082, -0.241541013121605, 
-0.0455610118806362, -0.382365942001343, -0.00278944987803698, 
0.0590433552861214, -0.328732430934906, 0.0665241554379463, -0.384352385997772, 
-0.104266256093979, -0.330000370740891, 0.638868570327759, 0.319561064243317, 
-0.373574942350388, 0.298344343900681, -0.394538104534149, -0.994185328483582, 
0.654802262783051, -0.0239639095962048, -0.14082495868206, 0.726947605609894, 
0.067158117890358, 1.09101295471191, 0.808771371841431, -0.511610448360443, 
0.873182356357574, 0.33600190281868, -0.62741494178772, 0.253036916255951, 
-0.717691659927368, 0.329070538282394, 0.364699423313141, -0.0409119315445423, 
-0.356035232543945, -0.00621286546811461, 0.333550602197647, 
-0.327464520931244, 0.163056030869484, 0.441578358411789, -0.463090926408768, 
0.791485249996185, -1.08877301216125, 0.0416726917028427, -0.581684827804565, 
0.389889031648636, -0.32378751039505, 0.184145957231522, -0.291793346405029, 
-0.046744417399168, -0.593223035335541, -0.619257867336273, -0.41385293006897, 
0.565666615962982, -0.486125022172928, 0.246443659067154, -0.0412923097610474, 
0.893342435359955, 0.337903827428818, -0.551677107810974, 0.401258170604706, 
-0.628006637096405, 0.148221224546432, -0.0568033419549465, -0.530756235122681
), vertical = c(-0.176369309425354, 0.474502354860306, 0.0566342882812023, 
0.611396670341492, 0.376279890537262, 0.59516716003418, -0.177679508924484, 
-0.549056708812714, 0.0260348655283451, -0.0717226788401604, 
-0.104350790381432, -0.202235117554665, -0.110944032669067, 0.147080093622208, 
-0.0262884516268969, 0.0451383702456951, 0.615623116493225, 0.445720255374908, 
0.0480968803167343, 0.400624185800552, 0.248091980814934, -0.716846406459808, 
0.11407159268856, -0.152194082736969, 0.0246401410549879, 0.150926142930984, 
-0.437859088182449, 0.0160182043910027, 0.20544721186161, 0.197501495480537, 
-0.0254431646317244, 0.218464657664299, 0.119692757725716, 0.0423489212989807, 
0.0680879354476929, 0.0461949817836285, -0.037192665040493, -0.0420530699193478, 
-0.252572000026703, -0.365248888731003, -0.542886137962341, 0.195641875267029, 
-0.243147045373917, 0.156293720006943, 0.128018841147423, 0.592842638492584, 
0.29944321513176, 0.0551972948014736, 0.0954329967498779, -0.230890363454819, 
0.291117131710052, -0.123327493667603, 0.298259824514389, 0.291962414979935, 
0.0570146627724171, -0.248049721121788, -0.147798582911491, -0.363093376159668, 
0.121045224368572, -0.186850875616074, 0.0238371174782515, 0.201136231422424, 
0.0619173347949982, -0.0573527812957764, -0.345680475234985, 
-0.637051165103912, -0.174467399716377, -0.155659765005112, -1.08539187908173, 
-0.414698243141174, 0.499438345432281, 0.0502946302294731, -1.10627043247223, 
0.559918701648712, 0.125187128782272, 0.52006334066391, -0.0163563191890717, 
-0.787765979766846, 0.10916892439127, 0.313010096549988, 0.167831897735596, 
0.128610551357269, 0.0104815689846873, -0.134907931089401, 0.116861052811146, 
-0.164915651082993, -1.09490132331848, -0.140782698988914, 0.54309743642807, 
0.206757411360741, 0.346103101968765, -0.108830809593201, 0.241710051894188, 
-0.327760368585587, 0.185540676116943), issue = c("issue", "issue", 
"issue", "issue", "issue", "issue", "issue", "issue", "issue", 
"issue", "issue", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", "party", 
"party", "party"), year = c("9999", "9999", "9999", "9999", "9999", 
"9999", "9999", "9999", "9999", "9999", "9999", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
"09", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", 
"13", "13", "13", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", 
"15", "16", "16", "16"), object_n = c("welfare", "ecolib", "ecoreform", 
"europe", "cultlib", "immig", "security", "defense", "edu", "env", 
"infra", "cons05", "lab_uk05", "libdem05", "union05", "spd05", 
"fdp_d05", "gr_d05", "linke/pds05", "övp06", "spö06", "fpö06", 
"gr_a06", "cda06", "pvda06", "vvd06", "sp06", "rpr/ump07", "psf07", 
"udf07", "svp07", "fdp_ch07", "sps07", "cvp07", "gr_ch07", "fg07", 
"ff07", "lab_irl07", "övp08", "spö08", "fpö08", "gr_a08", "bzö08", 
"union09", "spd09", "fdp_d09", "gr_d09", "linke/pds09", "cons10", 
"lab_uk10", "libdem10", "cda10", "pvda10", "vvd10", "rr_nl10", 
"sp10", "svp11", "fdp_ch11", "sps11", "cvp11", "gr_ch11", "fg11", 
"ff11", "lab_irl11", "sf11", "indep_irl11", "rpr/ump12", "psf12", 
"rr_f12", "cda12", "pvda12", "vvd12", "rr_nl12", "d6212", "sp12", 
"övp13", "spö13", "fpö13", "gr_a13", "union13", "spd13", "gr_d13", 
"linke/pds13", "cons15", "lab_uk15", "libdem15", "ukip15", "svp15", 
"fdp_ch15", "sps15", "cvp15", "gr_ch15", "fg16", "ff16", "sf16"
)), .Names = c("horizontal", "vertical", "issue", "year", "object_n"
), row.names = c(NA, -95L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Currently I use the code below to specify the plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(horizontal, vertical)) +
  geom_point(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="issue"),
             color = 'black', size=5, shape=3) +
  geom_point(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="party"),
             color = 'black', aes(shape=year), size=2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,15,17,10,11,12,18,13,14,7,8,9,0,5,1))+
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="party"),
                  aes(horizontal, vertical, label = object_n), size=2.5, family = "Franklin Gothic Demi") +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="issue"),
                  aes(horizontal, vertical, label = object_n), size=3.2,
                  family = "Franklin Gothic Demi",
                  fontface = 'bold') +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
```

This works fine, and produces the following plot:

[image]

However, the problem is that given I specify `geom_text_repel` for the two subsets, the labels will overlap, which kills the point of using this geom. Do you have any idea how to set it up in one `geom_text_repel` with conditional `size` and `face`? I have tried something similar to [what is suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361557/how-to-add-a-condition-to-the-geom-point-size), but I continuously run into an error: *ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval*

This is for example what I have tried:

```
ff <- function(issue){ifelse(dat$issue=="issue",3.2,2.5)}

mds <- ggplot(dat, aes(horizontal, vertical)) +
  geom_point(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="issue"),
             color = 'black', size=5, shape=3) +
  geom_point(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="party"),
             color = 'black', aes(shape=year), size=2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,15,17,10,11,12,18,13,14,7,8,9,0,5,1))+
  geom_text_repel(dat,aes(horizontal, vertical, label = object_n, size = factor(issue)),
                  family = "Franklin Gothic Demi") + scale_size_manual(values=ff(issue)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
mds
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

does this help you? Just making a new variable for `fontface` and using `scale_size_manual` to mimic your existing text sizing:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

# this is a nice helper fxn if you are using the same theme a lot :)
theme_set(theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
                  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                        axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                        axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
                        panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank()))

dat$ff <- ifelse(dat$issue == "issue", "bold", "plain")

ggplot(dat, aes(horizontal, vertical)) +
    geom_point(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="issue"),
               color = 'black', size=5, shape=3) +
    geom_point(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="party"),
               color = 'black', aes(shape=year), size=2) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,15,17,10,11,12,18,13,14,7,8,9,0,5,1)) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = object_n, size = issue, fontface = ff)) +
    scale_size_manual(values = c(3.5, 2.5))
```

Remember the final sizing of the text is going to be dictated partially by the size of the graphics device you are using to record. This is what it looks like as a png with a width of 800 px and height of 511 px:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(horizontal, vertical)) +
  geom_point(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="issue"),
             color = 'black', size=5, shape=3) +
  geom_point(data=subset(dat, dat$issue=="party"),
             color = 'black', aes(shape=year), size=2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,15,17,10,11,12,18,13,14,7,8,9,0,5,1))+
  geom_text_repel(data=dat,aes(horizontal, vertical, label = object_n, size = issue == "issue"),
                  family = "Franklin Gothic Demi") + scale_size_manual(values=c(1,5)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
mds
```

You do not really need a function, it is enough if you use `size = issue == "issue"` and further `scale_size_manual(values=c(1,5))` to choose the size

Additionally the error

> error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

appeared because you missed the `data=` argument in `geom_text_repel()`